# Circuit thermal analysis in PSPICE and temperature coefficients

Tags: resistors, simulation, temperature, thermal, pspice

I am tying to perform a thermal analysis in pspice. Resistors needs two temperature coefficients as TC1 and TC2 (if we assume linear change of R vs. T, it's zero) in pspice. But in resistor datasheets (like [this](https://www.vishay.com/docs/20035/dcrcwe3.pdf)) from Vishay, I've seen that TCR is for example **± 200 ppm/K**. What does this **±** mean? Why TCR is not a single positive or negative number? Thanks.

Comment: I suspect it means the coefficient is 0, plus or minus a small amount.

Comment: Thanks @jonk , probably that notation introduce an interval for TC values, but I am not sure.

Comment: Perhaps someone smarter than I am will add to this. I'm just telling you how I'd interpret it. Copper is somewhere around 3300 (or a little more) ppm/K. So those specs seem pretty good to me on that datasheet.

Comment: TCR explained by Vishay: [Non-Linearity of Resistance/Temperature Characteristic](https://www.vishay.com/docs/60108/nonlinea.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does **±200 ppm/K** mean?

These resistors ideally (are designed to) have a temperature coefficient of 0 (zero) meaning their value does not change **at all** over temperature. Of course this is impossible to produce reliably and in large quantities. So there will still be some temperature dependency.

That's what the **±200 ppm/K** describes.

The manufacturer aims for a **zero** temperature coefficient but they cannot always make that so what they end up with is either a positive or a negative temperature coefficient.

They could make the resistors such that they always have a positive or always negative temperature coefficient but I'd rather have the "near zero" temperature coefficient instead.

If I absolutely must have a certain temperature coefficient then I'd use a PTC or NTC maybe combined with some resistors.

It means that an increase (+) of the resistor's temperature by one Kelvin (= one degree Celcius) will increase (+) it value at most 200 ppm or decrease (-) it at most by 200 ppm.

Ppm means parts per mission so 1 ppm is 1 per million so 200 ppm is 200 per million = 200 / 1000000.

Example: a 1 Mohm resistor will change +/- 200 ppm = +/- 200 ohms per Kelvin.

One degree isn't much, let's take 100 degrees then 100 * 200 ohms = 20 kohm. That means the 1 Mohm resistor will have a value change of less than +/- 20 kohm over that 100 Kelvin range.

**If** the resistor was exactly 1.000 Mohm at 30 degrees celcius then its value would be between 1.000 Mohm - 20 kohm = **980 kohm** and 1.000 Mohm + 20 kohm = **1020 kohm** when the temperature is between -20 and + 80 degrees Celcius (that's 30 C +/- 50 C).

Note the "**If**" at the paragraph above, that's because I ignore the initial tolerance (accuracy) of the resistor. To keep it simple I'm assuming I have an absolute accurate resistor.

Pspice is designed for simulating resistors which are on **integrated circuits** (remember that Spice means: Simulation Program with **Integrated Circuit** Emphasis). On an integrated circuit you generally cannot "mix" the materials (for making resistors) such that the temperature coefficient becomes zero. Resistors are made in a certain material which has a certain temperature coefficient and that's it.

If you're lucky there will be a different resistor type available as well made from a different material which results in a resistor with an opposite sign temperature coefficient, then you can combine the two (two resistors in series) and get a (near) zero temperature coefficient.